# Как изменить формат datetime в mysql для отображения в виде dd.mm.yyyy MM:HH?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Как изменить формат datetime в mysql для отображения в виде `dd.mm.yyyy MM:HH` а не в американском формате?

И ещё вопрос. Что Вы используете - datetime или timestamp?

Comment: Месяц с минутами не путаешь? И что за `ММ:HH`?

Comment: ну да...смысл в том, что сперва день-месяц-год. Наверное буду использовать обычный bigint и хранить там timestamp , но заморочки на клиенте- как перевести нормально?

Comment: И зачем тут bigint?

Comment: предложите вариант на клиенте отображать в формате день/месяц/год и отсылать это на сервер- хранить это не важно как- и при загрузке- отображение в нормальном виде. Вот я чего-то уже второй день с какой-то датой вожусь- не могу разобраться-как быть?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по [мануалу](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp), должно быть так:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')
```